# action on page load to set marker on Google Maps probs

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an input where the user insert his address and after that when he click outside of the input a marker for the map is set.. THIS WORKS GREAT.

NOTE: IM setting marker on google maps..

```
$("#address1").blur(function()
        {
            loadCoordinates("");
        });
```

the problem is... When a user use the edit form.. wich uses the same javascript for set the marker... they need to click in the ipnut and then outside to set the marker

So i try to set the marker on document.load But this is not setting any marker on my map..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkVal = $("#address1").val();
if(checkVal==''){

}
else{
loadCoordinates("");
}
});
```

EDIT:

I even tried this :( also

```
$(function()
        {
            loadCoordinates("");
        });
```

Not working..

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? What kind of map? Is the issue with setting the marker or the blur event firing incorrectly? Either way, your script needs to know when not to override the existing marker in the map, so some sort of boolean toggle or something is needed.

Comment: but keyup will trigger until a key is pressed.. i need it before that on loading the page.. @BotskoNet , this is a Google Maps, the function to set markers works like charm, but i need to trigger on load.. In this moment you have to click the input (focus) then click on body... and then markers are set

Comment: it will trigger when key released. if you need to invoke your function on page load you need to use $(document).ready(function(){
loadCoordinates("");
}); because on page load you input more likely is empty and that's why your function is not invoked on page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like you need two different events to trigger the map load. There are a few choices based on your existing design, you're pretty close:

```
function loadCoordinates(){
  if( $("#address1").val() != '' ){ 
    // do the actual map pin load
  }
}
$(function(){

  // Load the coords on doc load
  loadCoordinates();

  $("#address1").blur( loadCoordinates );

});
```

Or, you could technically just call `$("#address1").blur( loadCoordinates ).trigger('blur');`

Comment: Sorry i try both but i couldnt make it work... Can i replace the blur function to a function based on everyload.. cause the problem is this just works if user lost focus :(

Comment: Paste your full code then because this code will: a) fire the loadCoord function on page load, b) trigger the loadCoord function on address field blur. I gave you two different ways of making this fire on page load - either calling loadCoordinates once, or forcing the blur event to trigger

Comment: Just trim it to the essential parts, or give us a link, or a reduced test case in jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks i think i found the issue , its has to do something with invocing loadCoordinates somewhere else i havent notice, this is a conflict i think.. will fix this.

Comment: Ok i removed that, the issue is the same.. pls check my code.. i have updated the question

Comment: The loadCoord function doesn't seem to matter, it's how you're calling it and when. Can we see this running  on a webpage? The original post shows you're still executing the method on blur only. My example code fires it on page load, then on blur.

Comment: I know, =( but the problem is i cant trigger the address input on load... just the blur works like charm.. its a shame a lot to code to post. even this is not woriking ..   $("#address1").blur( loadCoordinates ).trigger('blur');

Comment: I can't really see how your code is working, and i know from experience that my sample code does what needs to happen event-wise. Maybe you have another issue the marker can't be set right away, or the address is empty temporarily. Who knows. Can you post a public link? Make a reduced test case in jsfiddle and we can help

Comment: Yes i think this is setting a marker but a different one 
$(loadCoordinates(""));  . .. . What is the difference on trigger using the id of input and blur.. i will give you a link but there are other things there, but i promess they are not producing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Blur` event triggers when your element lost focus, if you want invoke your function earlier better to use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) but in that case you also need to check if current input value is valid for your function because `keyup` event triggered when user releases a key on the keyboard.